# Background Image appears to overflow container

Tags: css

I'm using Firebug to work on my CSS.

It shows the HTML, Body, and inner container all at 620px height. I assume my window is around 640px high.

Using firebug I can clearly see that all the elements end just short of the full height of the window, however the body bg-image appears to take up the whole window height, which is beyond the size of it's relative container.

How/Why is this?

Note: It is a Drupal site using normalize.css as a reset. When I talk about height there is no padding or margins on the content.

I've pushed to test, see here - http://mermaidriverpools.rickdonohoe.co.uk/

Comment: Please, post your code (or even better, a fiddle) so we can see what are you doing on it. Thanks

Comment: See edit to question.

Comment: Rick, please see my edit. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Rick, any update on this? if this solved your problem, please mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looking at your page, I'm as annoyed as you. But I think I have found why this is happening.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTF55/1/), you can see that the background properties (color, image...) extends all over the page **IF** it's specifically **ON** the body tag. It doesn't matter how big the body is (It's a 1x1 box in the fiddle).

It must be a browser behaviour. This doesn't change the actual size of the body. It will follow the normal rules (size is the same than content, a specific size if it's set or the same as the parent if inherit is set).

But in this [other one](http://jsfiddle.net/rPS5X/) (setting the background-color to an inner div with fixed dimensions) the background color doesn't extend all over the page.

Try to create a wrapper as a children of your body and place body styles on it.

```
<body>
  <div class="all your body classes here">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is a worthwile, hence the upvote. It was more the fact that the body didn't fill the whole screen (why is it short?) and why does this happen anyways, which meant there was room for a better answer. 

Seen as there isn't ACCEPTED.

Comment: @RickDonohoe sorry, perhaps I should explained it a little more. Setting background-(image or color, whatever) on body makes that property to take all over the page (even if body is only 1pxX1px size). But that doesn't mean that body has the same size. It will follow the normal rules for determining size (size of content, specific set you set, inheritance).

Perhaps we see different things? That's how your page currently looks like on my screen: http://tinypic.com/r/2d2cf8/5

I'll update my answer to better reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

if you use firefox browser you can press

```
ctrl+Shift+m
```

and paly withe resoltion you need